# What is wrong with makefile?

Tags: android, gnu-make, makefile

I'm trying to compile kernel of android, then get error.

```
/home/igor/work/hwp6s-kernel/arch/arm/mach-hi6620/pwrctrl/Makefile:9: *** missing separator.  Stop.
      File makefile
EXTRA_CFLAGS   +=   -wformat

obj-y               += common/
obj-y               += dfsMgr/
obj-y               += periMgr/
obj-y               += sleepMgr/
obj-y               += hotplug/
obj-y               += test/
EXTRA_CFLAGS -= -Wformat
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `-=` operator in makefiles.  Make is getting confused when reading this.

Even if that operator did exist (or you correctly  used `$(filter-out ...)`), you would not get your desired effect.   The `obj-y` is simply adding things to a list, which is processed after the kbuild makefile is read.  At that time, the `EXTRA_CFLAGS` value which existed at the end of reading the kbuild makefile would take effect.